# How to get unix timestamp interval between two datetime values most efficiently in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, intervals

This way surely works,but it calls UNIX_TIMESTAMP 2 times:

```
mysql> select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-09-23 22:07:42');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-09-23 22:07:42') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                           639 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.05 sec)
```

Comment: Do you actually want to know, or do you just like asking questions? Your profile shows 463 questions asked, but just 8 upvotes for answers you like!

Comment: Seriously,I actually want to know it badly.

Comment: That's fine, just looks curious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, now(), '2009-09-23 22:07:42')
```

do the same with just one function call (not counting `now()`)? (No access to MySQL right now and MSSQL works a little different, so can't test).

Basically a UNIX timestamp is the number of seconds since a weird epoch, so a difference is just a difference in seconds. Also, this function is only available in MySQL 5 and later.

But in general, worry about performance when you have a problem, write readable code until then.

Comment: Well, coming from MSSQL I started with DATEDIFF and looked around that whether there was something usable :-). But your answer has the same number of function calls, so no need to delete it, I think

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), '2009-09-23 22:07:42'))
```